ping not waiting on network failure
3B+
Raspberry Pi OS 32-bit (a critical app doesn't run on the 64-bit version; I tried)
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && reboot yesterday

I'm making an automatic shutdown script, with the assumption that the Pi will be on a battery backup, but the router that it's plugged into will not.  So when the router goes down (or I unplug the ethernet cable to test it), a periodic ping will start failing, and after some time of that failing, the Pi shuts down.
I remember doing this before, and at that time, ping gave me a consistent timeout regardless of why.  Now, it seems that the timeout in this scenario is much shorter than the 1 second that I told it, and somewhat variable.
So that makes it harder to have a consistent 5 minutes or so on battery, in case the power comes back and the router returns a ping again.

The script is:
#!/bin/bash

# Called from 00_startup_root.sh



# Router should not be backed up, so that it can be used to trigger a shutdown
ROUTER_IP=192.168.3.1



# Require this many consecutive seconds on battery before shutting down
TIMEOUT=300



echo
echo Ready!



# Are we consistently on battery?
# If yes, exit the loop, and shutdown
COUNT=$TIMEOUT
while [ "$COUNT" -ge "0" ]
do
    if ping -c 1 -w 1 "$ROUTER_IP" 2>&1 > /dev/null                             # Send 1 probe (-c 1), and timeout after 1 second (-w 1)
    then
        sleep 1
        # Present, which means
        # we're not on battery, so reset the count
        COUNT=$TIMEOUT
    else
        # Not present, which means
        # we are on battery, so run the count
        echo Shutting down in $COUNT seconds...
        COUNT=$(($COUNT-1))
    fi
done



# "Push the power button"
shutdown -h -P now

The intended redirection of stderr to /dev/null is another bug, which I have the solution for, but it works out nicely for this problem.  So I'll keep that bug until this problem is fixed.  The relevant part of 00_startup_root.sh is:
#!/bin/bash

# called from /etc/rc.local



cd $(dirname $0)

./01_ups-shutdown.sh 2>&1 | ts %Y-%m-%d_%a_%H:%M:%S >> ./01_ups-shutdown.log &

And 01_ups-shutdown.log is:
2024-07-23_Tue_08:05:29 
2024-07-23_Tue_08:05:29 Ready!
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:02 Shutting down in 300 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:03 Shutting down in 299 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:04 Shutting down in 298 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:04 Shutting down in 297 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:05 Shutting down in 296 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:06 Shutting down in 295 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 294 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 293 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 292 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 291 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 290 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 289 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 288 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 287 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 286 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:07 Shutting down in 285 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:08 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:08 Shutting down in 284 seconds...
...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:08 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:08 Shutting down in 126 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 Shutting down in 125 seconds...
...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 Shutting down in 2 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 Shutting down in 1 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:09 Shutting down in 0 seconds...
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:27 
2024-07-23_Tue_08:06:27 Ready!

As you can see from the timestamps, as soon as it figures out that the network itself is gone, the timeout goes away, and it quickly burns through the rest of the 300-count that was supposed to be 1 second each.  How to keep the 1 second each, when the network itself is gone?

Could you please explain how your question is about Raspberry Pi (or RPi OS)? AIUI, the Q seems to be about your router... am I wrong?

@Seamus The router is simply a host that sometimes goes away.  Nothing more.  When it goes away, the assumption is a power failure, and so I need to make sure it really is gone, and then shut down.  All of that logic is on the Pi, and it doesn't quite work yet, in the way that I described.

Like you already discovered, ping is smart enough to not wait for a reply if it has detected that the network interface is down completely or the specific host is unreachable.
Consequently, ping should not be used as time source. You should use another time source instead. For example, date -u +%s prints the time (epoch) in seconds.
Example script (note that this not display the message exactly every second, but will still do the check roughly every second, will timeout after roughly the specified timeout, and will not consume much CPU time by looping very quickly):
#!/bin/bash

ROUTER_IP=192.168.3.1
TIMEOUT=300

echo
echo Ready!

END_TIME=$(($(date -u +%s) + $TIMEOUT))

while [ $(date -u +%s) -le $END_TIME ]
do
    sleep 1
    if ping -c 1 -w 1 "$ROUTER_IP" 2>&1 > /dev/null
    then
        # Present, which means we're not on battery
        END_TIME=$(($(date -u +%s) + $TIMEOUT))
    else
        # Not present, which means we are on battery.
        REMAINING=$(($END_TIME - $(date -u +%s)))
        echo Shutting down in $REMAINING seconds...
    fi
done

There are ways to increase the timing accuracy if you think this is really important, but I hope this gets you in the right direction.
